# Gtkmm application crashes when dereferencing window object

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtkmm

I am trying to create simple application with `gtkmm` but I'm having some problem.

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

Here's the code to generate it:

---

MyWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MYWINDOW_H_
#define MYWINDOW_H_
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/frame.h>
#include "MyDrawingArea.h"

class MyWindow :public Gtk::Window {
public:
    MyWindow();
    virtual ~MyWindow() {}

private:
    MyDrawingArea drawing_area;
};

#endif /* MYWINDOW_H_ */
```

MyWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MyWindow.h"

MyWindow::MyWindow() : drawing_area("Drawing area") {
    set_title("My app");
    set_border_width(10);
    add(drawing_area);
    drawing_area.draw_stuff_in_area();


    show_all_children();
}
```

---

MyDrawingArea.h:

```
#ifndef MYDRAWINGAREA_H_
#define MYDRAWINGAREA_H_
#include <gtkmm/frame.h>
#include <gtkmm/drawingarea.h>

class MyDrawingArea : public Gtk::Frame {
public:
    MyDrawingArea(const Glib::ustring& title);
    virtual ~MyDrawingArea() {}
    void draw_stuff_in_area();

private:
    Gtk::DrawingArea area;
};

#endif /* MYDRAWINGAREA_H_ */
```

MyDrawingArea.cpp:

```
#include "MyDrawingArea.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

MyDrawingArea::MyDrawingArea(const Glib::ustring& title) : Gtk::Frame(title) {

    set_border_width(20);
    add(area);

    area.set_size_request(300, 250);
}

void MyDrawingArea::draw_stuff_in_area() {

    Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> cr = area.get_window()->create_cairo_context(); // program crashes here!
    // draw stuff with 'cr' here...

}
```

---

As the comment suggests, the program crashes when I try to create a `Cairo::Context`, though I don't think the `Cairo::Context` creation is the problem: **Every dereferencing to the object returned by my_area.get_window() crashes the program!**

Anyone know what's causing the problem?

Comment: Regardless of the null pointer, that's not the way to draw on a drawing area; instead connect to the drawing area's `draw` signal, and do the drawing in the signal handler. The signal handler will get a `Cairo::Context` passed to it, so you don't have to create one.

Comment: But what if I want to initiate the drawing, rather than wait for a signal?

Comment: So you just don't draw anything in your on_draw() until you want to. You have no real control over when your on_draw() will be called, but you get to decide what to do when it is called. By the way, there are many examples here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-drawingarea.html.en . But you might be more comfortable using GooCanvas, which lets you put shapes on a canvas, which then get drawn for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi did you check the return value of `area.get_window()` because [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a403777253417c5c7653aac9e932de76b) says

> Returns the widget’s window if it is realized, 0 otherwise.